# How to get Select items from Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I'm totally fresh to this. So I followed  a tutorial from [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html).

So far it's running, but I wonder how to create a new Book with existing Author.

My Book-Model is the following:

```
public class Book
{
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public int BookID { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public int Year { get; set; }
  [Range(1, 500)]
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  public string Genre { get; set; }

  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public int AuthorID { get; set; }

  // Navigation property
  public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

`AuthorID` would point to `Author.AuthorID` as in here:

```
public class Author
{
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public int AuthorID { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "First Name")]
  public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

In my `BooksController` is the following:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  ViewData["AuthorID"] = new SelectList(_context.Author, "AuthorID", "Author");
  return View();
}
```

but how can I use this `ViewData["AuthorID"]` in my `Create.cshtml` as `Form` `Select` `Options`?

Comment: You need to give a bit more context. What is the model for `Book` and what is the property of `Book` that you want to bind the selected Author to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways

### Solution 1

-Keeping the Controller code as it is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( i => i.AuthorID, 
     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["AuthorID"]);
```

Although it's better to change the name of the key in ViewData from AuthorID to AuthorList

### Solution 2

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  ViewData["AuthorID"] = _context.Author;
  return View();
}

@Html.DropDownListFor( i => i.AuthorID, 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["AuthorID"], "AuthorID", "Author"))
```

### Suggestion

Also I suggest to create a new class and use it as ViewModel, so instead of setting data in ViewData you can use that class Properties, for example

```
public class BooKViewModel
{
   Public IEnumerable<Author> AuthorsList {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  var viewModel = new BookViewModel();
  viewModel.AuthorsList = _context.Author;
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: What do you refer to by `i.AuthorRef`? When  trying **Solution 1** I'm getting `NullException` (using `i.AuthorID`)

Comment: The fk field in Book entity, I assume that it is AuthorRef

Comment: I only have `AuthorID` or virtual `Author`, but none of them set as fk.

Comment: @chrosey based on your edited question I have changed my answer

Comment: So I finally managed to accomplish the goal, thanks to your help. Solution 2 did it for me. But I could not try your suggestion, because another exception. The Page awaits a BookModel not BookViewModel. Is there any chance to bypass this?